# Problem with workflow running

Tags: 2013, workflow

I've started to learn SP workflows managing from SPD and VS. I use SP 2013 + SP1 and VS 2013 Ultimate. In my opinion everything looks good . I mean I installed and configured Workflow Manager and Service Bus, registered workflow service + tons of tips from Internet. Unfortunately I have a problem with workflow 2013 (2010 works good) running. I can publish workflows from SPD and VS but when I try to run I get message:

> Something went wrong. To try again ...

SP log shows:

> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ScopeInactiveException: Scope '/sharePoint/default/dcc425c8-8898-4e17-b222-3e95b854fa28/6c75ecec-d69d-4e20-ad0f-0c6699c9ca89' is not in an active state. Its current state is 'Unregistering'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 4d784df6-3aba-4368-951a-b4c4883a6b3f. NodeId: PL-AS00-TEST. Scope: /sharePoint/default/dcc425c8-8898-4e17-b222-3e95b854fa28/6c75ecec-d69d-4e20-ad0f-0c6699c9ca89. Client ActivityId : 2a1b609d-64fe-50f6-25a7-caf319eb640c. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.     at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequ...

but the scope is activated (checked directly in SQL DB)

Additionally I get Microsoft-Workflow event:

> Failed Service Bus Operation: System.OperationCanceledException: 40400: Endpoint not found..TrackingId:a8a311f8-96ba-4a85-a179-9cfca53ce15a_Gxx-as00-test,TimeStamp:2/17/2016 1:57:53 PM ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: 40400: Endpoint not found..TrackingId:a8a311f8-96ba-4a85-a179-9cfca53ce15a_Gxx-as00-test,TimeStamp:2/17/2016 1:57:53 PM ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 40400: Endpoint not found..TrackingId:a8a311f8-96ba-4a85-a179-9cfca53ce15a_Gxx-as00-test,TimeStamp:2/17/2016 1:57:53 PM

I use very simple workflow (only one stage - Write to history log).
I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already did this, but just in case, did you provide full control to the Workflow App?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved. The solution is to recreate site or use other. I didn't find out how to resolve using different method.